# values doesnt get passed to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was trying to send values received from my controller into my JavaScript and send it back to the controller function when the image is clicked.
so I have a table:

```
 <table >
      @foreach (var items in Model.StationList)
      {
           <tr>
             <td>
                 <a href="#" onclick="openDetail(@items.data1+','+@items.data2)"> 
                  <img src="~/Content/Images/detail_button.png"/>
                 </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
   　}
</table>
```

and the function in javascript is

```
function openDetail(data1, data2) {
        var url = "@Url.Action("Action1", "MyController")" + "?data1=" + data1+ "&data2=" + data2;
        window.location = url;
}
```

The action method is:

```
public ActionResult Action1(int? data1, int? data2)
{
  /// doing something with data 1 and data2 here 
}
```

When the value is passed, all I get is nulls.
Did I do something wrong somewhere?

Comment: What is your question? What is not working? What errors are your getting?

Comment: im getting nulls when the value is passed

Comment: And what are the `+` characters in `onclick="openDetail(@items.data1+','+@items.data2)"` for?

Comment: Debug your code! We don't know what your values are. We don't even know what the method your calling is.

Comment: the values arrived in the view when i put them inside a td. But when i clicked on the image and invoke the onclick function, all i get is nulls

Comment: Inspect the values of `data1` and `data2` in your `openDetail` method! (they are not `int`)

Comment: OH... stupid me adding the + ',' + to combine the data seems to have made it became a string and thus screwing up the whole function. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `items.data1` and `items.data2` persists then:

Replace

```
<a href="#" onclick="openDetail(@items.data1+','+@items.data2)">
```

With

```
<a href="#" onclick="openDetail('@items.data1', '@items.data2')">
```